# Create HTML dropdown list of music that can be played inside an audio player

Tags: javascript, html, audio-player

I am trying to create a simple music player for my website where the user can select from a number of different music tracks from a drop down list. The music is stored on our server.

This is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/rUf6j/7/ I just need to move the options into a drop down list.

**HTML:**

```
<audio id="player" controls="controls">
    <source id="mp3_src" src="/teachings/2011_01_09_Cut.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Flying in clouds</td>
        <td><a href="#" source="http://www.culturedub.com/assets/04-Forward.mp3">Listen</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Chilling on beach</td>
        <td><a href="#" source="http://www.culturedub.com/assets/04-Moringa-JahYu-Remix-feat-BaNdula-1.mp3">Listen</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[source]').on('click', function(){
        change( $(this).attr('source')  );
    });
});
```

**JS:**

```
 function change(sourceUrl) {
    var audio = document.getElementById("player"),
    source = document.getElementById("mp3_src");
    source.src = sourceUrl;
    audio.pause();
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply move links to `select` where `option` value is link to source and text is song name. Change event to `.on('change')`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#selection').on('change', function() {
    change($(this).val());
  });

});


function change(sourceUrl) {
  var audio = document.getElementById("player");
  var source = document.getElementById("mp3_src");

  audio.pause();

  if (sourceUrl) {
    source.src = sourceUrl;
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="selection">Listen:</label>
<select id="selection">
  <option value="">- Select track -</option>
  <option value="http://www.culturedub.com/assets/04-Forward.mp3">Flying in clouds</option>
  <option value="http://www.culturedub.com/assets/04-Moringa-JahYu-Remix-feat-BaNdula-1.mp3">Chilling on beach</option>
</select>
<br/>

<audio id="player" controls="controls">
  <source id="mp3_src" src="/teachings/2011_01_09_Cut.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Listens to the change event of the `<select>` and changes the audio based on the `<option>` value.

HTML:

```
<label>Select a track:
  <select id="songpicker">
    <option selected="" disabled>Select a track</option>
    <option value="http://www.culturedub.com/assets/04-Forward.mp3">Flying in clouds</option>
    <option value="http://www.culturedub.com/assets/04-Moringa-JahYu-Remix-feat-BaNdula-1.mp3">Chilling on beach</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#songpicker').on('change', function() {
    change( $(this).val()  );
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('#songpicker').on('change', function() {
    change( $(this).val()  );
})
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<label>Select a track:
  <select id="songpicker">
    <option selected="" disabled>Select a track</option>
    <option value="http://www.culturedub.com/assets/04-Forward.mp3">Flying in clouds</option>
    <option value="http://www.culturedub.com/assets/04-Moringa-JahYu-Remix-feat-BaNdula-1.mp3">Chilling on beach</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

Comment: Not only does that throw an error, but also isn't very helpful. Please add an explanation.