# drop down selection with clicking properties

Tags: javascript, audio

Hi i have a simple dropdown option that allows the user to select a sound to play once they decide to click the play button. it was working when i only had one sound available and they would just click on it but now i have multiple sounds and want to provide a drop down list. Im having trouble making it clickable. heres what i have.

```js
 var callButt = document.getElementById('callButt');
  var ringButt1 = document.getElementById("ringButt1");
  var play = document.getElementById("callButt");
  var player = document.getElementById("player");


      var num = -1;
      var rings = [];



      ringButt1.onclick = function(){
          rings.push("Basic_Bell.mp3");

      }

      callButt.addEventListener("click", function(){
      
         num++;
              if(num > rings.length-1){
                  num = -1;
                 
                  return false;
              }
              if(rings[num] != false){
                  player.src = rings[num];
                  player.play();
              }

      });
```

```html
<select>
 
  <option id='ringButt1'>Basic Bell</button>
  <option id='ringButt2'>Upbeat Bell</button>
  </select>
  <audio id='player'></audio>

  <button id='callButt'>CALL</button>
```

so what I'm trying to do is select an audio from the options (previously i just had a button i would click that would send the ringtone to the array and would play after i click the callButt) send it to an array then play when i click the call button. i apologize, i understand if it doesn't make any sense...

Comment: Hope this helps you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40279697/create-html-dropdown-list-of-music-that-can-be-played-inside-an-audio-player

Answer (score 0):

you can use the change event and handle the select change ( option selection)

check this for more

[Change event Handling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)

Answer (score 0):

There are some things which can be improved in your code:

- In the HTML, notice how you are opening `<option>` tags inside the `<select>`, but closing `</button>` instead. A select consists in a set of `<option>`s as described [for example here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select).
- In the JS piece, you don't really need to check for "clicks" on the select `<option>`s, you are just interested in the selected value. As @Partha mentions, you could check just for changes in the list selected option... but since you have a button to trigger the action, it's not even necessary to do that. You can always check the value of the `<select>` list when you are about to play the sound, and change the sound source URL accordingly.

I refactored your example to check for the selected value once you click on the button and then, retrieve the sound URL and play it.

```js
// Get references to HTML elements
var callButt = document.getElementById('callButt');
var animalSelector = document.getElementById("animalSelector");
var play = document.getElementById("callButt");
var player = document.getElementById("player");

// Keep a dictionary of sound urls by animal
var audioURLs = {
  "cats": "http://soundbible.com/mp3/Cat_Meow_2-Cat_Stevens-2034822903.mp3",
  "dogs": "http://soundbible.com/mp3/small-dog-barking_daniel-simion.mp3"
}

// When we detect a click on the button...
callButt.addEventListener("click", function(){
  // Retrieve the selected animal
  var selectedOption = animalSelector.value;
  
  // Check its sound URL from the dictionary
  var audioURL = audioURLs[selectedOption];
  
  // Update the player audio file and play it
  player.src = audioURL;
  player.play();
});
```

```html
<select id="animalSelector">
  <option value="cats">Hear cats</option>
  <option value="dogs">Hear dogs</option>
</select>
<audio id='player'></audio>
<button id='callButt'>CALL</button>
```